# php mysql merge multiple same queries into one

Tags: php, mysql

So i have some range from 1 to 40,

which i have to use in order execute different queries from the same table and column but from a different range like:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column > 1 && column <= 15");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column >=18 && column <= 30");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column >= 35 && column <= 38");
```

i get the total rows from these queries one by one for different actions... but how can i combine these 3 for example queries into 1 and get the same result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (column > 1 AND column <= 15) 
OR (column >= 18 AND column <= 30) 
OR (column >= 35 AND column <= 38)
```

// EDIT: OP Wants to Count number of rows for each condition:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE column > 1 AND column <= 15) AS count_1, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE column >= 18 AND column <= 30) AS count_2, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE column >= 35 AND column <= 38) AS count_3 
FROM table
```

count_1, count_2, and count_3 are the numbers of rows for each condition.

Comment: i want to get the number of rows from table where column is from range 1 to 15 , 18 30 and 35 38 seperately but in one query

Comment: @fxuser Can you elaborate what you mean by "separately but in one query"?

Comment: when i execute the 3 queries on my question i get 3 numbers for example 143, 4343 and 938 ... how can i make these 3 queries one and get the same result?

Answer (score 2):

**Heavily edited because I misread the question**

If you want all the rows you could just do:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column > 1 AND column <= 15) OR
  (column >=18 AND column <= 30) OR
  (column >= 35 AND column <= 38)
```

However, if you just want the count for each, that is not the right way to go about it. The count can be calculated directly in MySQL using `count(*)`. Even if you were to do three separate queries it would be better to use `count(*)` over selecting all the rows (it used much less memory).

With that said, you can get the count for all the rows like this:

```php
$query = "SELECT ".
      " (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE column > 1 AND column <= 15) AS count_1,".
      " (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE column >= 18 AND column <= 30) AS count_2,". 
      " (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE column >= 35 AND column <= 38) AS count_3";

$res = mysql_query($query);
extract( mysql_fetch_assoc($res) );

echo "The counts are $count_1, $count_2, and $count_3";
```

The `extract` function will take an associative array and set local variables for each item in that array. I just figured it would be easier to use than dealing with the array returned from `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

**Note:** @fn-n posted the SQL first, I just formatted it into PHP. I'd write it a different way except (s?)he already did it the right way :)

Comment: probably i didnt explain it as much as possible, currently i get all rows where column is from 1 to 15 etc... i do this 3 times and get different number of rows from each query.. i dont want to combine the query and get the total rows, i want to get the same different count of rows but in one query

Comment: So what is the end result that you want? Multiple PHP arrays each with the data set? MySQL can only return a single dimension of results but there are ways to separate the data out by doing some post-processing of the returned rows... is that what you need?

Comment: quote from my above comment:when i execute the 3 queries on my question i get 3 numbers for example 143, 4343 and 938 ... how can i make these 3 queries one and get the same result?

Comment: @fxuser Ah, so you need to get the same value as if you had done three queries and called `mysql_num_rows`? Do you need the data too or just the count?

Comment: @fxuser Got it. The reason we were so confused is that it is not typical to get all the rows in order to just get the count. That is what `count(*)` is for and it uses much less memory and is much more efficient. I updated my answer with an example.